# Как изменить размер шрифта, внедрённого при помощи Сufón?

Tags: javascript, шрифты

Сгенерировал js-файл шрифта при помощи [Сufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/%20%22%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%22.). [Получилось мелко](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ujecmikb). Как увеличить размер? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить строчку `Cufon.set("fontSize", "100");`(где 100 — размер шрифта в пикселях), [увеличилось](http://cssdeck.com/labs/3csy7ohh). Нашёл ответ [здесь](http://xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/typographics/cufon), где также рассказано и про остальные опции. Спасибо.

Comment: Так и с помощью обычного свойства `font-size` [тоже работает](http://cssdeck.com/labs/xfuv6wsi)